# Why can't I pass an array of pointers in C++ as an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

In my program, I created an array of pointers as:

```
Employee* staff = new Employee[MAX_CAPACITY];
```

And then I attempted to pass the array to a function with parameters like this:

```
void enter_employee_data(Employee* n[], int i)
{
     // code goes here
}
```

But that gets me a lot of compiler errors saying "member reference base type 'Employee *' is not a structure or union."

I found that the program works fine if I make the parameter of the function a pointer that is not an array:

```
void enter_employee_data(Employee* n, int i)
{
   // code goes here
}
```

And the program also works fine if I make the parameter of the function just a regular array with no *:

```
void enter_employee_data(Employee n[], int i)
{
      //code goes here
}
```

This doesn't quite make sense to me. Why does the parameter `Employee n[]` work but not `Employee* n[]`? It seems like it should be the other way around to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very low quality and with a search you can find many results!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
Employee* staff = new Employee[MAX_CAPACITY];
```

You allocated an array of employees.  But this function declaration:

```
void enter_employee_data(Employee* n[], int i)
```

expects an array of pointers to employees.  So you have a problem with different types of parameters.  `Employee n[]` and `Employee* n` are both valid types that can access the memory you allocated, which is why they work.

Comment: Do you mean that it would work if I created the array as: `Employee* staff = new Employee*[MAX_CAPACITY];`

Comment: @Raddicus: Your problem starts with the first sentence of your question, "I created an array of pointers". You should reread your book until it's clear why that statement is wrong.

Comment: @Raddicus What Blastfurnace is saying is that you never allocated an array of pointers, just an array of objects.  So you should research how to allocate an array of pointers to objects, and then use that information to properly call your function.

Comment: @Joel & Blastfurnace: Sorry for asking dumb questions, but thanks for the information.

Comment: @Raddicus: It's not a dumb question. Arrays, pointers, and manual memory management can be confusing. I think new learners should start with C++ containers like `std::vector` and save `new` until much later.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to a function as Employee n[] or Employee* n. That is we need to pass a pointer to the array. Employee* n[] implies an array which stores the pointers and each pointer points to an employee. But you do not have any array which is storing pointers.